# ActivitySceneTransitionBasicSample setViewName

Tags: android

has anyone compiled ActivitySceneTransitionBasicSample project, this is a error"cannot find symbol method setViewName(String)",I can't find this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setViewName` method was removed from the time L-Preview and API 21 were released. It looks like ActivitySceneTransitionBasicSample was setup with L-Preview, but you are using API 21.

Check this link to see the change log showing where the method was removed:
https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/preview-21/changes/android.view.View.html